# How to open a .htmlENX file

Tags: html, security, file-extension

I have found some .htmlENX files on my computer and I know that these are encrypted files using the Egis program.  That's all I've been able to determine from the file name.
These files are just chat logs from an old computer but I'm very interested in gaining access to them. Does anyone know how?

Comment: What is 'the EGIS program'? Please edit and add a link. Someone on the [McAfee forum](https://community.mcafee.com/thread/49389) states *Acer computer users know this program as Acer eDataSecurity*

Answer (score 1):

According to the simple tutorial at [this website](http://www.file-extensions.org/egis-file-extensions), you will need to download the Egis software in order to read data encrypted by it. This is standard practice with most computer applications using proprietary formats or unique file extensions. In particular:

> The HTMLENX file extension is used by Egis for its encrypted HTML files. [1](http://www.file-extensions.org/egis-file-extensions)

You can find the download for the software you originally used through a basic internet search, and it should come at the Egis package. It may need to run in compatibility mode if you're on Windows 10. As mentioned by the above comment, this software is also rebranded and packaged as "**Acer eDataSecurity Management,**" so there's a chance it will already be on your computer if you use Acer.